# Will playing "Eyes of Heaven" without reading the manga spoil the player majorly?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I have been interested in getting *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Eyes of Heaven* for PS4 but I'm afraid of story spoilers.

Is the story mode of *Eyes of Heaven* a supplement for the manga, or do I need to read the books first to understand?

Answer (score 4):

The game has a story mode that literally starts at the ending of part 3 and it pretty much spoils all deaths in the JoJo universe.
I also think it has a lot of details (like references, interactions between specific characters, special moves and even specific variations of gameplay) that can be enjoyed and understood only by someone that read the manga and knows about JoJo. 
So I suggest you read the manga if you don't want to get some nasty spoilers.

Answer (score 1):

Nooooo! It will be a bad idea. They will tell you lots of things about JoJo that you don't know and the story will reveal spoilers that will be major.